# How to chain a multi-feature search in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have a 3 filter search for a job. One is for the job title/decription/company, one for job category for e.g Banking and one for the location for e.g New York

How do I chain the query such that it should render me the appropriate results if I specified any one filter and if I specified all 3 it should perform an AND. I tried doing it with if else, but it is becoming too long. Is there another way?

Here is my code:

views.py

```
 if request.method == "POST":
        internship_desc = request.POST['internship_desc']
        internship_ind = request.POST['internship_industry']
        internship_loc = request.POST['internship_location']

        results = []
    
    
       if internship_desc != "" and internship_desc is not None:
            query_results = Internship.objects.filter(
                Q(internship_title__icontains=internship_desc) |
                Q(internship_desc__icontains=internship_desc) |
                Q(recruiter__company_name__icontains=internship_desc)
            )
    
        if internship_ind !="" and internship_ind is not None:
             if internship_desc != "" and internship_desc is not None:
                query_results = query_results.objects.filter(
                industry_type__iexact=internship_ind)
        else:
            query_results = Internship.objects.filter(industry_type__iexact=internship_ind)

        if internship_loc !="" and internship_loc is not None:
            if internship_desc != "" and internship_desc is not None and internship_ind !="" 
               and internship_ind is not None:
                 query_results = query_results.objects.filter(
                 industry_type__iexact=internship_ind)

            query_results = query_results.objects.filter(
            recruiter__company_region__iexact=internship_loc)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to do.

```
result = Internship.objects.all()
if internship_desc:
    result = result.filter(internship_desc__icontains=internship_desc)
if internship_ind:
    result = result.filter(industry_type__iexact=internship_ind)
if internship_loc:
    result = result.filter(recruiter__company_region__iexact=internship_loc)
```

Comment: @E Paul, thanks ! It was simple. I tried a longer way

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is using `django_filters` for these sort of filtering.

```
import django_filters

class InternshipFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    company_name = django_filters.CharFilter(
        field_name='recruiter__company_name',
        lookup_expr='icontains'
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Internship
        fields = {
            'internship_title': ['icontains'],
            'internship_desc': ['icontains'],
        }
```

and pass it to template like this:

```
context['filter_form'] = InternshipFilter().form
```

and use it in your view to return the filtered objects:

```
InternshipFilter(self.request.GET, queryset=Internship.objects.all()).qs
```

more info [here](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Comment: @Poonya, thanks but not so comfy using forms :)